# Oscillation, diameter and limsup

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ be an interval. By definition $\text{diam}f(I)=\sup_{x, x'\in I}|f(x)-f(x')|$, $\text{osc}(f, I)=\sup_{x\in I}f(x)-\inf_{x\in I}f(x)$ and $\text{osc}(f, x_0)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\text{osc}(f, B_{\epsilon}(x_0))$.

Is it true that
$$\text{diam}f(I)=\text{osc}(f, I)$$
and
$$\text{osc}(f, x_0)=\inf\{\text{osc}(f, B_{\delta}(x_0)):\delta>0\}=\limsup_{x\to x_0}f(x)-\liminf_{x\to x_0}f(x)$$
?
I think so but I want to be sure.

Comment: yes it is. Because the convergences are monotonic.

Answer (score 0):

On the real line  diameter of any set $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ can be expressed in terms of its $\inf$ and $\sup$, namely  $\operatorname{diam}A = \sup A-\inf A$.  (At least of every *nonempty* set; I don't want to deal with the  [diameter of empty set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/579373) right now.) In particular,  $\operatorname{diam} f(I)=\operatorname{osc}(f, I)$.

The equality $\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\operatorname{osc}(f, B_{\delta}(x_0)) =\inf\{\operatorname{osc}(f, B_{\delta}(x_0)):\delta>0\}$ follows from the fact that oscillation is a nondecreasing function of $\delta$.

The equality $ \operatorname{osc}(f,  x_0)  = \limsup_{x\to x_0}f(x)-\liminf_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ is also correct, but with the caveat: on the right we might have $\infty-\infty$ or $(-\infty)-(-\infty)$, neither of which is particularly meaningful. In both those cases $f$ is unbounded in every neighborhood of $x_0$, which makes the left side $\infty$.