# The null space in metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, definition

In one of my books about metric spaces, it is stated that "a not null set, equiped with a metric, is a metric space". On the other hand, the null set as a subset of $R$ is a compact subspace as it is complete and totally bounded.... Why is there such a contradiction?Thanks.

Comment: This is probably something that is going to vary from text to text.  The discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025149/is-the-empty-metric-space-complete) might help.

Comment: You have an unbalanced quotation mark in there; it's hard to tell which part is the quote.

Comment: What is the "contradiction" you're talking about?

Comment: @joriki  sorry for the quotation...it is fixed now.

Comment: @Ron   the contradiction is whether a metric space can be null or not

Comment: Is $\varnothing$ a metric space?  One book rules it out, another may not rule it out.  Why do you need to know?  That is, for what purpose?

Comment: @JairTaylor , nice link! I think I am ok now. thanks.

Comment: @GEdgar cause....I am a Vigro and I need to clarify everyhting in maths! Sorry I am kidding..The real reason is that I had to solve an exercise determining all the compact set in a discreat metric space

Comment: Compactness it a topological property, and from the definition it follows that the empty set is compact. I don't get the part where you compare this with whether or not it is a metric space.

Comment: What book are you using?  I would suggest finding a better book, if your book claims a metric space cannot be empty.  See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45145/why-are-metric-spaces-non-empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author decided to require metric spaces to be non-empty. This is not a definition I would adopt (see [Why are metric spaces non-empty?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45145/why-are-metric-spaces-non-empty) for example) but it does not *contradict* anything.

If we follow this definition, then $\varnothing$ is still a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but it is not recognized as a metric space of its own. Not a contradiction.