# $f(x) =\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$ continuity and uniform continuity

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $f(x) =\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$where $x \in (0, 1)$ and $0<\alpha \le 1$. Is $f$ continuous? What about uniform continuity?
Justify.

I know this function is continuous in the given domain for all such $\alpha$
but how do I show it rigourously?

For uniform continuity I need to show for any $\epsilon >0$ $ \exists \delta >0 $ for which $\vert x-y \vert < \delta\implies \vert f(x) - f(y) \vert < \epsilon $

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $0<\alpha\leqslant1$, we have
$$f(x) = x^{-\alpha} = \exp\left(-\alpha\log x \right), $$
so continuity follows from the composition of continuous functions.

However, given the Cauchy sequence $x_n=\frac1n$ in $(0,1)$, we have
$$f(x_n) = \left(\frac1n\right)^{-\alpha} = n^\alpha\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow\infty, $$
so $f$ is not Cauchy-continuous, and therefore not uniformly continuous. To see this more explicitly, fix $m$ and consider the behavior of $|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @SMath be sure to see the revised answer; my original one had an error.

Comment: There are many ways to show that if  $S$ is a bounded non-empty subset of $R$ and $f:S\to R$ is unbounded then $f $is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: Thanks @user254665 - although "non-empty" is not needed since any function defined on the empty set is trivially bounded :)

Comment: OK.I was being overly cautious. I'd rather be redundant than wrong.

Comment: Indeed. Although the empty set is not a very interesting metric space, it is necessary to include this trivial case, cf. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45145/why-are-metric-spaces-non-empty