# Is the tuple (∅,{∅}) a measurable space?

Tags: measure-theory

Assume the set {∅} is a σ-algebra on ∅, related discussing is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3316045/660389).

So, is the tuple (∅,{∅}) a measurable space?

Comment: an algebra of sets must contain at least two elements

Comment: @AlvinLepik Thanks for your comments, please discuss that topic [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3316045/660389)

Comment: We have many such questions in mathematics.  So it is important when to insert the word **nonempty** into a definition or statement.  The oldest example is whether $1$ is a prime.  Another example:   is $\varnothing$ a topological space?  If so, is it connected?  Is it compact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Book](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes.pdf),

> Definition 1.5 A measurable space (X, A) is a non-empty set X equipped
>   with a σ-algebra A on X

your tuple is not a measurable space.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for requiring that $X$ be nonempty?

Comment: If I want the **category** of measurable spaces and measurable maps to have the **best** properties of a category, then should I or should I not include this emptyset?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for requiring that $X$ be nonempty except that some mathematicians have a pathological desire to exclude the empty set.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45145/why-are-metric-spaces-non-empty for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a measurable space.  You may occasionally encounter some authors who require a measurable space to be nonempty but this is not the standard definition and it is a completely artificial and unnecessary restriction.